# How to display a long list of FAQ on a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, lists, app, faq

I am designing the FAQ page for a complex mobile application. Faqs can be more than 20 and text might be very long. I have tried to list them with an accordion solution first but it seems to be heavy and not completely usable.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried combining the collapsable accordion along with a detail view?
It gives a nice fluid feeling, especially when the expand/collapse animations are done properly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Accordion can be a good solution, if it would be combined with some kind of categories. You can just split all your questions to 4-6 categories for example. 
You can also use any other layout instead of accordeon, but categorizing is a must in any case here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a scrolllist for the FAQ questions instead of a accordion. If you press e.g. on "Question 3" the detail view for question 3 is moving smoothly from right to left. If you press on "< Back" the FAQ list is moving from left to right. In addition you can offer buttons to switch to next or previous question in the detail views.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMZPC9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvL18E.png)</sup>

Comment: This is a nice solution but users might be forced to do too many selections to get to the answer. Consider that they get to the FAQ section by selecting FAQ menu item on the product page. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's a good way. The FAQ section should contain questions about the product and processes (context sensitive informations). But an option to explore and search all FAQ topics from this point is also useful.